# Determine conditions on $a$ and $b$ such that $f \circ g$ = $g \circ f$.

Tags: functions

I have this problem:

> Let $f$ and $g$ be the following straight line functions: $f(x) = ax + b$,
>   $g(x) = cx + d$. Determine conditions on $a$ and $b$ such that $f \circ g$ = $g \circ f$.

This is what I got:

$$ad-d=cb-b$$

and then

$$a(d - d/a) = b(c-1)$$

Is it correct?

Thank you

Comment: Yep that's correct!

Comment: $a(cx+d)+b=c(ax+b)+d\Rightarrow acx+ad+b=acx+cb+d\Rightarrow d(a-1)=b(c-1)$ thus if $a\neq 0$ you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition very nearly works perfectly, but it *doesn't work* if $a=0.$ Instead of factoring out $a,$ you should factor out $d,$ giving you $$d(a-1)=b(c-1).$$